# Adding submit button to end of input field Rails Bootstrap simple_form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

```
rails 6
bootstrap
simple_form
```

I have a views/books/index.html/slim, as follows:

```
#BooksIndex
  table.table.table-striped.table-hover
    thead
      tr.d-flex
        th.col-10
          = t('books.name')
        th.col-1
        th.col-1
    tbody
      - @Books.each do |Book|
        tr.d-flex
          td.col-sm-10 = Book.name
          td.col-sm-1 = link_to edit_Book_path(Book)
            i.fas.fa-edit.fa-lg
          td.col-sm-1 = link_to Book, data: { confirm: t('are_you_sure') }, method: :delete
            i.fas.fa-trash-alt.fa-lg
#AddBookForm
  = simple_form_for(@Book || Book.new) do |f|
    .form-inputs
      = f.input :name, placeholder: t('Books.views.index.enter_name_of_Book_you_like_to_add'), label:false
    span.form-actions
      button.btn.btn-primary type="submit"
       = "Create Book"
```

The #AddBookForm produces the following view:
[image]

When I submit, it produces the following:

```
Started POST "/Books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-12 12:46:44 -0700
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"....", "Book"=>{"name"=>"Fun"}}
```

I would like to have the Submit button, at the end of the text input field, like this:

[image]

I tried different variations of span, and using columns, but it's always showing up on the next line. Any ideas?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#auto-sizing

Comment: This works when using the GRID system. My question is specific to simple_form's helpers

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of a bootstrap question, but here it goes

```
 = simple_form_for(@Book || Book.new), html: { class: "form-inline" } do |f|
   = f.input :name, placeholder: t('Books.views.index.enter_name_of_Book_you_like_to_add'), class: "form-control", label_html: { class: "mr-2"}
  button.btn.btn-primary.ml-2 type="submit"
   = "Create Book"
```

I added the label_html property so you can specify the label tag since that part is supposed to be shown according to your expected result.

Check the syntax, since I'm used to haml. but if you want the codepen to see how it looks check this:
https://codepen.io/jean182/pen/ZEGxWQB

Comment: I will test this out. I was hoping I can use the input_group and append functionality, with simple_form, but I have yet to figure it out, if the button is a submit type

Comment: This does not work with simple_form, I am getting an uexpected end of input error

Comment: Try to indent the code properly, I just send you a bare snippet with the classes you need in order to make it work, but I'm not sure if the syntax is right since I have not used slim just haml

Comment: It does not work. You can send it in erb if you like, and I can translate it